# Who can give me a link for the operator= of vector in MSDN?

Tags: c++, operators

Who can give me a link for the operator= of vector in MSDN?

Why I can only find operator[]?

If operator= is just something default,  like copy everything in A to B, how this following code works?

```
vector<double> v(100,1);
v = vector<double>(200,2);   // if operator= is just a trivail version, how to make sure the old v get cleared?
```

Comment: Why don't you just do a search for it?  It's listed under "vector operators" along with `operator[]`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673471(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: You kinda just asked this question. Why don't you edit your old question and tag this on? Also, see the comment I left on your other question. You're worrying too much, let vector do it's job; it'll clear everything, I promise. I'm voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Come on! The reason I ask this is because there is NO operator= for vector in MSDN, which confused me.

Comment: @8888: James links to it in his comment.

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem, STL in VS2010 has operator=, but that in VS2003,2005,2008 don't.

Comment: Ok, I admit that is a bit interesting... it is indeed missing from earlier versions of the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` is part of the STL, so any description of `std::vector` will do. The underlying implementation may differ slightly, but all conformant versions of STL must provide the same interface and the same guarantees for `std::vector`. I can't find in quickly on MSDN, but here are two such descriptions of `operator=`:

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator=/
2. http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html

Now, the second part of your question puzzles me. What would you expect `operator=` to do on a vector if not "copy everything from A into B"?

In your example, your question was "how to make sure the old v get cleared?". I can interpret this in one of two ways: You might be asking "how do I know that this assignment `v = vector<double>(200,2)` will overwrite the contents of `v` and not append to it?". The answer is that you know that because that's the definition of how `operator=` works for STL containers. Any standards compliant implementation is guaranteed to work that way.

You might also be asking "what happens to the contents of `v` when I overwrite them using the assignment `v = vector<double>(200,2)`?" The answer is that they are deallocated, and if they are objects, their destructors are called. Note the important distinction that if the vector contains *pointers to* objects, the pointers themselves are deallocated, but *not* what they point to.

If I didn't answer your question, please try to clarify it.

Comment: My question is more like your second interpret.
You said "The answer is that they are deallocated", but HOW if you just have a operator= COPYING every member in B.member to A.member without explicitly deallocating old A.member.

Comment: @8888: Who says it just copies every member?

Comment: So, what i am saying is that there should be a special operator= for vector doing the following thing:

void operator=(vector& B)
{
    erase elements in A
    resize A
    copy elements from B to A
}

Comment: @8888: That's exactly what there is. (Well, different function type.)

Comment: right, nobody said it just copies. The fact that I didn't find it in MSDN(2003~2008) leads me to think that way.

Comment: @8888:  All documentation is bound to have errors, and consulting a second (and third) source is always a good idea.  If all else fails, the source for `std::vector::operator=` is in `<vector>`; you can open it up and take a look.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and suggestions!